# Slow For-Loop (Apps Script)

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I'm a novice and I'm pretty sure I haven't set up the for-loop correctly in my function "importData":

```
function urlsToSheets(){
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/d3cd48afaacd4913b923fd98c6591276_36.csv", "Pavement Condition");
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/lahub::tctmc-streets-of-significance-construction-impacted-streets.csv", "Streets of Significance");
    importData("https://geohub.lacity.org/datasets/lahub::one-year-moratorium-streets.csv", "One-Year Moratorium");
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/lahub::boe-permits-lines.csv", "BOE Permit Lines")
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/lahub::archived-boe-permits-lines.csv", "Archived BOE Permit Lines");
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/lahub::boe-permits-points.csv", "BOE Permit Points");
    importData("https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/56318ef6ed6444d981977adf80157b87_5.csv","Archived BOE Permit Points");
}

function importData(url, sheetName){
    const file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    const csvData = csvToArray(csv);
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.clear();
    for (let i = 0; i <= csvData.length; i++){
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[i].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
}
```

Each of these URLs have thousands of rows; the first URL has 85k rows of data. It takes over 10 minutes for the csvData to transfer to its intended sheet.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this quicker?

Thank you!

Comment: What's `csvToArray`?

Comment: another function that I use to clean up the csv blob-turned-string and convert it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the data for each row, set values of a double dimension matrix. The less interactions you do using the SpeadsheetApp API, the faster your code gets.

I suggest creating an array of all of your data. Then selecting the rows and setting values in separate lines (out of for loop).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! The simplest solution was to take the following code out of the for-loop and to make it its own line.

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData)
```

Thank you!